# how to break lpSolveAPI in R?

Tags: r, timeout, lpsolve

In my code I'm running several iterations each of which solves an LP problem using lpSolveAPI. In some cases the LP takes an excessive amount of time, so I want to set a time limit so that I can skip the current iteration and go to the next one.

```
for (i in 1:1000)
{
  #create LP model for problem for instance i
  solve(model)
}
```

I already tried:

```
solve(model,timeout = 10, time_limit = 10)
```

and:

```
evalWithTimeout(solve(model), timeout = 10, onTimeout = "error")
```

but in both cases the LPsolver keeps working the same way as if I had not specified a time limit.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Get rid of the problems that take an excessive amount of time. In general LP's dont take so much time to solve unless you have integer constraints. I would suggest that you look at NEOS servers

Comment: It would be good if you flushed this out into a fully reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/lpSolveAPI.pdf) of lpSolveAPI package, use

```
lp.control(model, timeout = 10)
status = solve(model)
```

The methods you've tried don't work because solve ignores all arguments except the first one, and evalWithTimeout can't interrupt C code.